# Wiring diagram for IE58A (Incremental-Encoder)

Tags: wiring, encoder

I have an incremental-encoder, the cable is torn and I opened it and find 8 wires. I'm now really confused how can I understand what are wires for. I want to replace the encoder with a new one so I have to know what each wire is for?

```
Type : IE58A
Pin: bn    k0         Pin:rt
Pin:gn     k0 neg     Pin:sw
Pin:gr     +Us=11-27v Pin: bn 0.5
Pin:rs     0Volt      Pin: ws 0.5

6 thin wires are : 
   + grey
   + pink
   + orange
   + brown
   + black
   + red

2 thick wire:
   + brown
   + beige
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you do any better with the photos? They look out of focus _and_ motion blur. Link to datasheet for the encoder? Welcome to EE.SE. You should ask an actual question in your post too - otherwise it is an interesting collection of statements.

Comment: @transistor I apologize for that. I edited it now.

Comment: That was the most rapid upskilling of photographic skills I've seen! Answer on the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet gives a few clues.

[image]

*Figure 1. The datasheet tells us (1) that we'll need power, (2) there's a signal A and /A output pair, (3) a signal B and /B output pair and (4) a zero reference (once per revolution) signal Z and /Z pair. At two wires each that makes eight wires.*

You don't need to reverse engineer this unit any further. You need to find a compatible encoder (watch the pulses per revolution) and figure out the wiring back to whatever is using this one.

Further reading:

- [How do I get a position from an encoder?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/227905/how-do-i-get-a-position-from-an-encoder/227936#227936).

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer given by transistor, since I'm assuming the encoder connector is still good, [this page](http://www.tr-electronic.de/f/ST1876) gives the signal assignments. No need to mess around figuring out what goes where.

Pin Designation Description Level Driver NCColour

1 CH_A_OUT Channel A 11-27V Push Pull yellow

2 /CH_A_OUT Channel A inverted 11-27V Push Pull violet

3 not connected

4 CH_B_OUT Channel B 11-27V Push Pull pink

5 /CH_B_OUT Channel B inverted 11-27V Push Pull white

6 not connected

7 CH_I_OUT Channel Reference 11-27V Push Pull green

8 /CH_I_OUT Channel Reference inverted 11-27V Push Pull brown

9 not connected

10 not connected

11 Supply Voltage IN Supply voltage 11-27V red

12 Ground IN Ground 0V blue

Note that the wire colors do not seem to apply to the internal wiring.